# JPA Relationship Order and Product

Tags: jpa, orm, entity

Consider the following scenario. 
There are Products (eg. Cakes, Cup cakes, muffins and etc) with fields "id", "name", "price". 
An order can have multiple products with quantities. In a relational DB it should be 3 tables. Order, Product and Order_Product (with orderId and productId as primaryKey and a "quantity" column). But I am not sure about the relationship in JPA for this scenario.

There relationship between Order and Product needs to be One-To-Many. But am confused where column "quantity" (number of products) should come.

Order Entity

```
@Entity
public class MyOrder implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long Id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private Set<Product> product;
}
```

Product Entity

```
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private double unitPrice;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: First of all are you facing any errors ? what are they?... second: quantity should be coming from order. isn't it ? put the quantity in Product bean

Comment: There should be no direct association between Order and Product. An Order should have a OneToMany association with an OrderedProduct entity, which itself should have a ManyToOne association with Product. Add an autogenerated ID to OrderedProduct, too, instead of using a composite primary key, and your life will be simpler.

Comment: @JBNizet That was my initial idea. But is it the optimal solution? BTW thanks for the reply.

Comment: @AmitP There is no error coz I did not implement it. I wanted to clarify the relationship before the implementation. 
The "Quantity" column should not in either Order or Product entity coz it does not belong to any of those.

Comment: Well, it's the one that fits with your use-case. What would be not-optimal about it? Why don't you make something that works and does what you want before thinking about how optimal it is? An optimal solution that does not work or does not do what you want is useless.

Comment: In JPA relations cannot have "attributes" (like the quantity). You have to use another entity, like the `OrderedProduct` as already mentioned.